# Get data from webpages with Python

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, web-applications

Looking to get data from a specific website with Python to upload onto Google App Engine. The idea is to create a database data to store the information on the server to retrieve and display in an web app.

```
  from google.appengine.ext import webapp
  from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
  from google.appengine.ext import db
  import os
  import datetime
  from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template


 # A class which creates all the pokemon on the server
 class Pokemondata(db.Model):
 number = db.IntegerProperty()
 pokemonname = db.StringProperty()
 description = db.StringProperty()

 newpoke = Pokemondata(number="001",pokemonname="Balbasuar",description="The grass       pokemon")
 newpoke = Pokemondata(number="002",pokemonname="Ivysaur",description="The seed pokemon")
 newpoke = Pokemondata(number="003",pokemonname="Venasaur",description="Another grass pokemon")
 newpoke.put()

  # A class to put new pokemon in to the server ?
 class ApplyHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
   def post(self):
   self.session = Session()
   pnumber = self.request.get('number')
   pname = self.request.get('pokemonname')
   pdescription = self.request.get('description')

    newpoke = Pokemondata(number=pnumber,pokemonname=pname,description=pdescription)
newpoke.put()
    self.session['pokemon'] = pname
     doRender(self,"board.htm",{})

  # Construct a google table for this data
  # to display
  class JSONInterface(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
      que = db.Query(Pokemondata)
      listing = que.fetch(limit = 12)
      doRender(self,'http://pokedexapp.appspot.com/?user=cater54321@gmail.com#input',
        {'listing':listing})


   application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/(.*html)?', ApplyHandler),
     ('/json', JSONInterface)], debug=True)


  def main():
     run_wsgi_app(application)
     if __name__ == "__main__":
         main()
```

When I do deploy the app to test I am getting server error. Can anyone tell me if this is a step in the right direction and what needs amending?

The yaml file currently is

application: pokedexapp
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.py

Comment: I understand the code indentation is wrong. I am currently trying to fix it

Comment: You want to post the error you're getting.

Comment: Can you post .yaml file? I see some errors here, where is class MainHandler, JSONInterface, SearchResult that you use in handler?

Comment: I have amended the code somewhat and added the contents of the yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
# A class which creates all the pokemon on the server
class Pokemondata(db.Model):
number = db.IntegerProperty()
pokemonname = db.StringProperty()
description = db.StringProperty()


def post(self):
self.session = Session()
pnumber = self.request.get('number')
pname = self.request.get('pokemonname')
pdescription = self.request.get('description')


newpoke = Pokemondata(number=pnumber,pokemonname=pname,description=pdescription)
newpoke.put()
self.session['pokemon'] = pname
doRender(self,"board.htm",{})


Page = """
<html manifest="my.manifest">
<head>
       <!--  All the js and css header links go here -->
</head>
<body>
      <!-- all the needed HTML markup -->

      <!-- if there is a place you would need to embed values (e.g. a user name), just use %s in its place, e.g. -->
<h1>%s's App Engine App</h>
      <!-- you can now do a string substitution for the each %s (in order) - see end… 
</body>
</html>
   """       


# A class to get / put pokemon in to the server ?
class ApplyHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.session = Session()
    pnumber = self.request.get('number')
    pname = self.request.get('pokemonname')
    pdescription = self.request.get('description')

    newpoke = Pokemondata(number=pnumber,pokemonname=pname,description=pdescription)
    newpoke.put()
    self.session['pokemon'] = pname
    doRender(self,"board.htm",{})

# Construct a google big ass table for this data
# to display

    def get(self):
        que = db.Query(Pokemondata)
    listing = que.fetch(limit = 12)
    doRender(self,'http://pokedexapp.appspot.com/?user=cater54321@gmail.com#input',
             {'listing':listing})    

   #self.response.out.write( page % "Fred Bloggs")
   # This is standard Google App Engine stuff - create a WSGI application
   # framework and set up the routing between URIs and Handlers...
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', Pokemondata),
                                         ('/json', JSONInterface)], debug=True)
def Addlist():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__Addlist__":
    main()
   code here
```

Comment: Whats the example supposed to do?

Comment: The example should get data created in the code and post it to the server... Html has been left out for formatting the output but its just a matter of displaying the results of the database entries

Answer (score 0):

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

# A class which creates all the pokemon on the server
class Pokemondata(db.Model):
pokemonname = db.StringProperty()

newpoke = Pokemondata(pokemonname="Balbasuar")
newpoke.put()

class JSONInterface(webapp.RequestHandler): 
    def post(self):
        pkmname = self.request.get('pokemonname')
        callback = self.request.get('callback')
        # This line makes the Message object...
        pkmname  = Pokemondata(pokemonname=pkmname)
        # This one pushes it to the database (a Big-Table)...
        pkmname.put()
        self.response.out.write(getJSONMessages(callback))

    def get(self):
        callback = self.request.get('callback')
        self.response.out.write(getJSONMessages(callback))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext import db
import os
import datetime
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

# A class which creates all the pokemon on the server
class Pokemondata(db.Model):
    def get(self):
        pokemonname = db.StringProperty()
        newpoke = Pokemondata(pokemonname="Balbasuar")
        newpoke.put()

class JSONInterface(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        pkmname = self.request.get('pokemonname')
        callback = self.request.get('callback')
        # This line makes the Message object...
        pkmname  = Pokemondata(pokemonname=pkmname)
        # This one pushes it to the database (a Big-Table)...
        pkmname.put()
        self.response.out.write(getJSONMessages(callback))

    def get(self):
        callback = self.request.get('callback')
        self.response.out.write(getJSONMessages(callback))
```